# OpenGL ES Fill Effect

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How to create a fill effect? I have an irregular closed shape created using:

```
   glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
        (.......) 
   glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
   glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);
        (.......) 
   glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
```

Now I would like to have an "fill/paint bucket" effect like in photoshop. The background inside the shape is white (for example) and by clicking inside the shape I want to change the color to red or green.

Can somebody give me some hints, please.

[image]

Comment: Can it be you mistake OpenGL for something that it just isn't and has never been?

Comment: Yes, it can be true. But.... i don't know what could solve my issue. i've never used OpenGL before, but it looks like this is it. Maybe I describing my problem in wrong way.

Comment: You described The problem quite obviously. It's just that OpenGL is the completely wrong tool to solve it. If you've never used it before, then this particular problem is definitely not a reason to start using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you render a set of points and want OpenGL to "magically" fill the enclosed region. That's not possible. OpenGL doesn't realize that these points enclose some region. You don't even draw a line strip, it's just a set of points. Even a human has to put in a reasonable effort of thinking to see that the points "enclose" a region, let aside a computer, or just a simple interface for drawing points, lines and triangles onto the screen.

Instead of drawing points, just draw a polygon (use `GL_POLYGON` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_POINTS`). But if the enclosed region is non-convex that won't work in all cases. What you always have to realize is, that OpenGL is nothing more than a drawing API. It just draws points, lines and triangles to screen. Yes, with fancy effects, but all in all it just draws simple primitives. It doesn't manage any underlying graphics scene or something. The moment a primitive (like a single point, line or triangle) has been drawn, OpenGL doesn't remember it anymore.

What you want to achieve (given you at least change the point set to a line loop that really encloses a region), is not to be achieved by simple means. In the simplest case you need some kind of [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) that fills the region you enclosed by the lines. But for this you don't profit from OpenGL in any way, as this requires you to analyse the image on the CPU and set individual pixels. And neither can shaders do this in a simple (or any?) way.

Comment: have a look at the image I have added to the question. There has to be a solution to this ;/

Comment: @klm_ Yes it's just that this solution has nothing to do with OpenGL. Look at the flood-fill link I gave. That is the easiest way to solve it. But like said it doesn't have anything to do with OpenGL.