# CGMutuablePath and GLPaint

Tags: paint, bucket, eaglcontext

Referring to this question :[OpenGL ES Fill Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812309/opengl-es-fill-effect) 
 I am trying to do the samething  , but I have Custom UIView , which contains different CGMutuablePath and only drawing is enabled in selected UIView.

I have used GLPaint, PaintingView class and used it as a custom class to even draw different paths, everthing is working fine. except that I need to fill those paths too. When he user want to use a bucket paint effect. As I am using defined CG closed paths, is it possible to fill those paths using EAGLContext . I have tried in many ways to fill it with CGContextRef , but it always end up with "Invalid context" , I guess its not possible to use 2 differnt context in single view.

Can any body help me with this problem? How can I fill my path using EAGLContext ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to grasp the problem here without any actual example of your code/app. However, it seems you're trying to fill a stroked path.

Firstly, I don't know why you're suggesting two contexts here? You're drawing `CGMutablePaths` using a `CGContext` but you're trying to fill them using `EAGLContext`? That's quite a far fetched solution to the problem. `EAGLContext` is OpenGL ES (usually 3d stuff) and `CGContext` is Quartz 2D. Unless you have specific reasons to do so, I wouldn't recommend mixing both contexts in a single view without proper application.

You say you've tried everything to fill the paths? Which means you've already tried `CGContextEOFillPath` and `CGContextFillPath`? Anyhow, this should work with `CGMutablePaths`:

```
// Draw your CGMutablePath

CGContextAddPath(yourcgcontext, yourcgmpath); //Adds a previously created Quartz path. 
CGContextClosePath(yourcgcontext); //Closes and terminates the current path’s subpath.
CGContextClip(yourcgcontext); Modifies the current clipping path.

// Fill a solid or a gradient or an image, that should be clipped to your path.
```